# CSS Aligning multiple text parts

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align three text parts, where the middle part has a max-width and can be truncated using the text-overflow:ellipsis property.

e.g. The site | www.aLongNameShouldBeTruncated.com | is opening

should be aligned like this:

[image]

I can get it to work for chrome, see http://jsfiddle.net/LSuRx/5/:

But I can't get the three parts to vertically align nicely in IE9 and FireFox:

[image]

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `vertical-align: bottom;` to `#addressContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding `vertical-align: top;` into the #addressContainer block.

That worked for me under FF 14 and Opera 12.

Answer (score 1):

Give **vertical-align:top** to your `span`. Write like this:

```
span{vertical-align:top;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LSuRx/7/

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
div.ord{
    white-space: nowrap;  
    overflow: hidden; 
    float: left;
}

div.elip{
    max-width: 100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>

<div class="ord">Text 1</div>
<div class="ord elip">Your long address text will be here</div>
<div class="ord">Text 2</div>
```